# Add toolbox icon from the class I derive

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I derive a button like this:

```
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(Button))]
public class cButton : Button
{
}
```

And I want it to have the same icon as `System.Windows.Forms.Button`, what attributes do I have to apply?

Comment: I don't think you can use the Microsoft bitmaps — you would have to create (er, copy) your own and put them in resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use IL disassembler, reflector or something like Resource Hacker to find image of Button in resources then use `[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(Button), "foo.Resources.Button.bmp")]`